# Monaco: Syntax highlighting for multiple languages in single document

Tags: ide, monaco-editor, monaco-languageserver, monarch

I would like to have syntax highlighting for multiple languages in single file.

Just like the markdown monarch example in which you can embed different languages inside a code block and specify the language.

Since markdown is implemented using monarch, its achieved using `nextEmbedded` operation.

In my case I would like to take the built in JSON syntax which is not implemented using monarch and define that json values should be parsed as my own language.

`{"key": "<<< MY LANGUAGE HERE>>"}`

I'd expect this feature to be somewhere inside `IToken` structure but its not there.

Any demonstrations how to specify a different language for a token?